# CSS div:hover exclusion

Tags: html, css

I have two `div`s, one inside the other. When I `hover` over the outer one, I would like to change its color, no problem. But when I `hover` over the inside one I would like to change only its color. Is this possible? In other words, when `hover`ing over the inner div, I would like to see the out red "ring".

```
<div id="test"><div></div></div>

#test {
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
#test:hover {
    background-color: white;
}
#test div {
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}
#test div:hover {
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not with plain CSS. If you're hovering over a child, you are necessarily hovering over its parent(s).

However CSS4 plans include something that may help:

```
#test! div:hover {background-color: red;}
```

The `!` will make `#test` the subject of the selector, so it will select `#test` if it contains a `div:hover`, and re-apply the red background to it.

Comment: Btw., what browsers do support this?

Comment: Very few, if any at all. Some versions of Firefox or Chromium might have it.

Answer (score 0):

Not nesting the div will work.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qCUsy/):

#### HTML:

```
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="ttt"></div>
```

#### CSS:

```
#test {
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

#test:hover {
    background-color: white;
}

#ttt {
    background-color: green;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 60px;
}

#ttt:hover {
    background-color: white;
}
```